# My Laravel App doesn't work on Facebook

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, laravel, laravel-3

My Laravel App doesn't work on Facebook, seems like it gets confused on the routes.

This is my routes.php:

```
Route::get('ingresar', array('as' => 'ingresar', 'uses' => 'ingresar@index'));
```

This is my controller ingresar.php:

```
class Ingresar_Controller extends Base_Controller{

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index() {
        echo "Controller Ingresar";
    }
}
```

When I open my app on Facebook I get 404 error.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you accessing to apps.facebook.com/<namespace>/ingresar ?

Comment: Im not using canvas yet, just the tab.

Comment: your app should respond to /

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Facebook apps send POST requests when loading your app in its iFrame. There's also a payload it sends (via $_POST data) with relevant information (app id, user id and some other data).

You may also want to set that controller/method to POST.

```
Route::post('ingresar', array('as' => 'ingresar', 'uses' => 'ingresar@index'));
```